# I’m making this story that has a blown up planet, and I’m trying to have some animals and creatures that live here that have changed or been modified

Tags: creature-design, earth-like, fauna, bio-mechanics, mechs

So In this story the main planet has been blown up way before the point of the story taking place, and well I have most of the architecture down I’m stuck on coming up with creatures to inhabit it and was hoping for suggestions, here’s the main layout of the areas of the World. The world in question has people living in it who have very Medieval type landscapes and architecture but have some highly advanced technology such as Mech Suits that they use to fight with in Arena Battles. Also you cannot use Magic, there is no Magic in this world, you can use mixed things or more mythical looking things, but no Magic things.

First off you have **The Hell Star**

The Hell Star is the former Core of the planet, and well I do have a dormant dragon inside of it and it’s said that this thing is so gosh dang hot that no living thing would be able to survive living there (excluding the dragon of course) but I do think some stuff could be living near it for a heat source.

Next is **The Sea Floor**

The Sea Floor is a ring of water that runs around the Hell Star it is big enough and deep enough to house some monster sized creatures but I don’t want to many of them in here, I feel like it would strip it of some realistic feel since you don’t see Kaiju Fights from there every other day, Also you have Viking type people sailing on this and their homes are their Boats.

**The Land Mass**

The Land Mass is a bunch of Island like land chunks that survived the explosion of the planet you have places similar to the U.K., Rome, Italy, Africa, New York, Greece, Scotland, Ireland, Texas, Japan, and Russia, as well as some unique locations such as

**The Outlands**

The Outlands are a Bare Wasteland full of Ice and Blizzards, hardly any resources grow there and it’s said any human who has gone there has yet to come back alive.

**The Wolf Pack’s Forest**

The Wolf Pack is a group of mysterious travelers in my story that live here, but it’s manly a forest with trees that scales to be over 300 feet tall, there are plenty of resources here, you just got to look for them.

**The Junkyard**

The Junkyard is the smallest of the Land Masses, barely any plants or recourses grow there and it houses all the scraped Mechs and Machinery of the Land Masses, essentially a dump heap.

It’s also important to note, The New York based place is nothing but Skyscrapers and tall buildings connected together by wires that are attached to each over, hover turbines, and the Arena in the center of it all. And the Italy based place is near the Sea Floor but not touching it.

That’s about it, I thank everyone who puts in their thoughts, and thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you're asking for here. Requests for suggestions, discussion or lists of things are off-topic on this site. Also, I can't really tell what the nature of your world is... are all these things just kinda floating in a big bubble of atmosphere? Because you're gonna be needing some magic to have all that work and remain stable.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. We're pretty strict about our question and answer format. This means that each post must ask only one question, and that the questions be specific, answerable and not opinion based. As written it looks like you're describing 6 different regions, and are asking our thoughts about them. This makes your post have 6 broadly defined questions. Can you take a moment to read through our [help-center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) and [edit] your post to ask a single well defined question?

Comment: I suggest this question should be more specific. As it stands it is too broad.

Comment: Nyctophobia457 sphennings Understood, apologies about that

Comment: @StarfishPrime Sorry about not making it clear, what I was trying to ask was what type of creatures could possibly survive these conditions or possibly any animals surviving by adapting to these conditions, and if so what would be reasonable forms they would take on? I’ll think over how to trim down the question, but first I’m gonna check to see if there are any similar posts that could have answers to these questions.

Comment: Also thank you for the welcome @sphennings

Comment: @Trianus Asking what creatures could survive in one environment is probably too broad a question for this site, (given how many critters live in basically every environment on earth). Expanding that by a factor of 6 is definitely too broad. In general a good question on this site should be asking about 1 specific problem you're looking to solve rather than trying to spark conversation, idea generation or brainstorming. I'd strongly suggest you [edit] your question to greatly reduce it's scope.

Comment: Looks like you must have magic to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Trianus yes, but what about the planet? has it blown up? what state is it in now? are all the bits just floating around in a big bubble of atmosphere?

Comment: Conflating explosion and inflation is causing a splendid diversion from the point of the question (which though interesting's way too broad). You can use the [edit] function to bring the question to within the site's rules, then it'll be eligible for re-opening.

Answer (score 3):

Blowing up a whole planet like this would send the atmosphere and hydrosphere way off into deep space ending all life and potential for life, and if things are still close enough together for your people to move between debris without a long space journey, then resistance between bodies will cause rapidly decaying orbits making the whole planet come back together very quickly... so I would argue that sans magic (or some very advanced [Clarke Tech](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ClarkesThirdLaw)) at play, there could be no life or planet that meets this description.

That said, I think your idea is very interesting.   There will not be any scientific answers to support the existence of such a place; so, instead you should simply accept that this setting will be a fantasy environment of sorts.  Since realism is already out the window, I would say it is best to invent lifeforms that best support the narrative of your story rather than trying to make them believably exist in their biomes.

Answer (score 0):

**Hell Star:** No animals (too dang hot).

**Sea Floor:** Sea animals. Fish, jellyfish, anemones, whales, plankton, crabs, . . .

[image: Crab]

**Land Mass:** Land animals. Mice, rats, voles, shrews, marmosets, elephants, earthworms, . . .

[image]

**Outlands:** If there is water there can be phytoplankton and stuff that eat the phytoplankton. Fish, penguins, seals, polar bears, whales, . . .

[image]

If there is no water then nothing lives here.

**The Wolf Pack’s Forest:** Forest animals. Birds, squirrels, hedgehogs, badgers, foxes, stoats, . . .

[image]

**The Junkyard:** Maybe some forms of extremophile bacteria that feed off rust and sunlight.   Maybe some humans come from elsewhere to scavenge machine parts. But they bring their own food. The lack of soil precludes everything else.